# How to simulate Poisson point process

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, computational-number-theory

How to simulate a process $S_t=\sum_{0\leq s\leq t}\Delta_s,$ where $\Delta_s$ is a Poisson point process with values in $(0,\infty)$ and with characteristic measure $\Pi(dx)=\frac{\alpha}{\Gamma(1-\alpha)}x^{-1-\alpha}dx, \alpha=0.5,1,1.5.$  This means for every Borel set $B\subset (0,\infty),$ the counting process $N_\cdot^B=Card\{s\in [0,\cdot]:\Delta_s\in B\}$ is a Poisson process with intensity $\Pi(B).$

I am a fresh student on simulation. It would be nice if you can give me a program (Matlab or Mathematica) of a simple case.  Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What is $\Gamma(0)$ (the case $\alpha = 1$)? Your notation is irritating.

Comment: $\Gamma(0)=1$, this is the notation for book given by "Bertoin"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume we know how to simulate a  Poisson point process with constant intensity in an interval (e.g. by considering partial sums of i.i.d. exponential variables.)

That allows you to simulate a standard Poisson point process in a rectangle $[a,b] \times [0,d]$ by simulating an intensity $d$ Poisson process in $[a,b]$ and assigning the resulting points $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^T$ uniform heights $\{y_i\}_{i=1}^T$ in $[0,d]$ to obtain $\{(x_i,y_i)\}_{i=1}^T$.

To simulate (with a small error $<\epsilon$ in total variation) a Poisson point process with slowly decreasing integrable intensity $f(x)dx$ in $[0,\infty)$, first pick an increasing sequence $\{N_k\}_{k \ge 0}$ with $N_0=0$, e.g. $N_k=2^k-1$. Then pick $m$ large enough so that $\int_{N_m}^\infty f(x) \, dx <\epsilon$, so we can neglect points beyond $N_m$. Then for each $k=0,1,\ldots m-1$ independently simulate a standard Poisson process in a rectangle $[N_k,N_{k+1}] \times [0,f(N_k)]$. For each $k$ this yields points $(x_i(k),y_i(k))$
for  $1 \le i \le T_k$. Reject those points for which $y_i(k)>f(x_i(k))$.
Note that with $f$ decreasing polynomially and $N_k$ increasing geometrically, the rejection probability is bounded away from 1. The $x$ coordinates of the surviving points will yield a sample from a Poisson process with intensity $f(x)\, dx $ in $[0,N_m]$.

Comment: According to your process, you simulate a Poisson process, right?  According to my understanding, Poisson point process is a slight difference with Poisson process.  You can see the post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/248390/what-is-the-difference-between-a-poisson-process-and-a-poisson-point-process

Comment: I was simulating Poisson point processes.